# How I can receive hardware key events in sleep mode?

Tags: android, hardware, key, broadcastreceiver, sleep

I'm writing an application that allows people in danger to call 911.

This is how it should work:

1. He (or she)  feels danger.
2. He pushes the volume-down key three times.
3. My app calls 911.

But I'm facing the following problem:  how can I receive a hardward key event **in sleep mode**?

I've searched Google and other search engines, but can't find anything related.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourBoardcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                        Intent main = new Intent();// 
                }
        }
}
```

And in your Manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="YourBoardcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: You're welcome, If it worked out for you, you can apply the green tick mark

Comment: Hello Reno, Is it possible to capture the volume up and down buttons during sleep mode? I am able to get it working when the screen is unlocked. Any inputs is greatly appreciated!! I am particular about getting events in sleeep mode for volume buttons

Comment: What if the device does not have a camera action btton ?? and the device is on sleep mode(or screen off mode) then how to receive the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think you could do that is with a `BroadcastReceiver`, but it seems that the volume buttons do not generate an Intent when the screen is off (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712601/android-capturing-volume-up-down-key-presses-in-broadcast-receiver)). The closest thing you might be able to do is use the camera button to do something similar.

Perhaps it is better this way, anyway, though. I imagine it would annoy users if their phone called 911 while in their pocket because of the volume buttons, or the camera button too for that matter. Also, it's not something I would expect to happen.

Comment: thank you for your advise.
but how i can receive camera button event in sleep mode?
i need detailed method like using BroadcaseReceiver ......
thank you.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to receive volume up and down events when my phone is in sleep mode, I gone through most of the answers in this forum, no concrete answer that is possible or not. Some of the Android phones, doesn't camera button like HTC. Any help is greatly appreciated... I am looking only for events for the volume buttons when the device is in sleep