# Detect Camera button in sleep mode

Tags: android

Is there anyway to detect hthe camera button in Sleep mode? I tried the examples explained in this forum, but nothing works in Sleep mode.. I am llooking for this for a long time, but no proper answers..

[How I can receive hardware key events in sleep mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924241/how-i-can-receive-hardware-key-events-in-sleep-mode)

Please help me...

```
public class YourBoardcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                        Intent main = new Intent();// 
                }
        }
}
And in your Manifest :

<receiver android:name="YourBoardcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. When the device is put in sleep mode, almost all apps are paused or stopped. Only enough of the processor is kept on to be able to receive calls and SMS texts, and manage alarms and notifications. Apart from that, pretty much everything is discontinued.

If you want to keep detecting it when the screen is off, you will need to acquire a wakelock to prevent the device from going into sleep. However, if you do this all the time it will have an impact on the users' battery life.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that most Android devices do not have a CAMERA button... :-)

Comment: I am planning to develop some applications, that will help the users to call the emrgency number whenever there is an emergency, most of the smart phones are passwords protected, so it is little difficult to unlock the phone and dial the number.. I tried volume buttons and camera button, both are not working as epxected in sleep mode.. I dont want to drain the battery... any other thoughts?

Comment: The lock screen already has an emergency call option, so I don't really see the need for this.

Comment: I wnated to give them an option to call their parents number or local police number

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to be possible with the public SDK.

Comment: Raghav, I am not going to override the existing emergency button, I am going to do something custom that too on a different button right? I wanted to enhance in such a way, the end users are comfortable calling  during emergency. If you are panic sometimes mind may stop working, if they know there is a simpler way to initiate a call, then it would be easier for the end user

Comment: I get what you want to do, but it is not possible on Android.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22999/discussion-between-ramesh-and-raghav-sood)