# MediaPlayer as a service ignoring volume keys when screen locked

Tags: android

I have a music player service , using a MediaPlayer set to stream type STREAM_RING. It works fine when i change volume pressing the volume keys as long as the screen is not locked or off. How do i set my service to respond to these keys even in locked screen mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based off this question, it looks like it's not possible to capture volume up/down presses when the screen is locked. [Android capturing volume up/down key presses in broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712601/android-capturing-volume-up-down-key-presses-in-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. When [Spotify](http://spotify.com) is running and the screen is locked it's possible to change the volume.

Comment: I assume they're running on the MEDIA stream, which will be properly turned down when the screen is locked. I'm not sure of the RING stream though. Have you tried the MEDIA stream instead of the RING stream?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Do you mean STREAM_MUSIC or am I missing something? Is there any documentation for this behavior?