# Android - broadcast receiver for device physical buttons

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Is there any way to set a broadcast receiver that will fire when a button on the device (`power, home, volume`) is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: Home you can defininately not catch. You have to modify your OS for that. I can think of the same for the others...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712601/android-capturing-volume-up-down-key-presses-in-broadcast-receiver